# Simple Haskell key value file store

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

As an exercise in learning Haskell, I implemented a simple key value store, where you can put and get values (as `ByteString`s). (For reference this is inspired by this [short note describing bitcask's design](http://downloads.basho.com/papers/bitcask-intro.pdf)). I'd appreciate feedback on any aspect (style, *'haskellyness'*, library usage etc.) of my implementation:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

module KV (
    evalKV,
    putKV,
    getKV,
    liftIO
) where

import Prelude hiding (mapM)
import Data.Traversable (mapM)
import Control.Monad (liftM, liftM2)
import Control.Monad.State (StateT, evalStateT, get, put, liftIO)
import qualified System.IO as IO
import Data.ByteString.Lazy (ByteString)
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as L
import qualified Data.Binary as B
import qualified Data.Binary.Get as G
import qualified Data.Map as M

type Header    = (Integer, Integer)
               -- keysize  valuesize

type ValueInfo = (Integer, Integer)
               -- offset valuesize

type Key       = ByteString

type Pair      = (Key, ValueInfo)

type Index     = M.Map Key ValueInfo

data KVState = KVState
    { kvHandle :: IO.Handle
    , kvIndex  :: Index
    } deriving (Show)

type KV a = StateT KVState IO a

evalKV :: FilePath -> KV a -> IO a
evalKV p s = IO.withBinaryFile p IO.ReadWriteMode $ \h -> do
    i <- readIndex h
    evalStateT s $ KVState h i

putKV :: ByteString -> ByteString -> KV ()
putKV k v = do
    (KVState h i) <- get
    vi <- liftIO $ writePair h k v
    let i' = M.insert k vi i
    put $ KVState h i'

getKV :: ByteString -> KV (Maybe ByteString)
getKV k = do
    (KVState h i) <- get
    liftIO $ lookupKV h i k

readHeader :: ByteString -> (Header, Integer)
readHeader c = (h, fromIntegral o)
    where (h, _, o) = G.runGetState B.get c 0

readAt :: IO.Handle -> Integer -> Integer -> IO ByteString
readAt h o sz = do
    IO.hSeek h IO.AbsoluteSeek o
    L.hGet h $ fromIntegral sz

readPair :: IO.Handle -> Integer -> IO (Maybe Pair)
readPair h o = do
    IO.hSeek h IO.AbsoluteSeek o
    b <- L.hGet h 10 -- TODO: qualify this arbitrary number
    if L.null b
        then return Nothing
        else do
            let ((ksz, vsz), l) = readHeader b
            k <- readAt h (o + l) ksz
            return $ Just (k, (o + l + ksz, vsz))

writePair :: IO.Handle -> ByteString -> ByteString -> IO ValueInfo
writePair h k v = do
    IO.hSeek h IO.SeekFromEnd 0
    let l = fromIntegral . L.length
    let vsz = l v
    let t = (l k, vsz) :: Header
    L.hPut h (B.encode t)
    L.hPut h k
    p <- IO.hTell h
    L.hPut h v
    return (p, vsz)

readIndex :: IO.Handle -> IO Index
readIndex h = liftM M.fromList $ ri 0
    where ri o = do
            mp <- readPair h o
            case mp of
                Just p@(k, (vo, vsz)) -> do
                    t <- ri (vo + vsz)
                    return $ p : t
                Nothing -> return []

lookupKV :: IO.Handle -> Index -> ByteString -> IO (Maybe ByteString)
lookupKV h i k = mapM r mv
    where r = uncurry $ readAt h
          mv = M.lookup k i
```

And usage would look like:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import KV
import Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8

main = evalKV "test" $ do
    u <- getKV "asdf"
    liftIO $ print u
    putKV "asdf" "qwer"
    v <- getKV "asdf"
    liftIO $ print v
```

Which would result in the following output:

```
Nothing
Just (Chunk "qwer" Empty)
```

One concern I have, in particular, is that I've currently made no consideration for allowing concurrent access to the store, if people have opinions on the best approach for this I'd be really interested to hear them. I have this concern as, if I get time to work on this some more, my intention is to create a way to access the store over HTTP/TCP.

Answer (score 2):

Why not:

```
type KeySize   = Integer
type ValueSize = Integer
type Header    = (KeySize, ValueSize)
```

Instead of commenting, like you did here:

```
type Header    = (Integer, Integer)
               -- keysize  valuesize
```

Same about `ValueInfo`.